# How to combine soft-max value from two or more neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, estimation

Consider a scenario where we have some input variable $X$ (maybe an image), which goes through several noisy path and we generate $K$ noisy observations:

\begin{align}
Y_i = X_i +Z_i, i \in \{1,\ldots, K\}
\end{align}
where noises are independent.  Here I am assuming additive structure but it doesn't have to be.

Suppose that I use the same neural network on $Y_i$'s to classify.
Also, suppose that I have access to the soft-max values In particular, let $p_i$ be the soft-max value for input  $Y_i$,

**Question:** How do I combine these values in the best way to determine my class? One option is
\begin{align}
p_{new}   = \frac{1}{K} \sum_{i=1}^K p_i 
\end{align}

One can also just threshold at $0.5$ and find the majority.

I am looking for an answer that would have some theoretical backing.

Answer (score 0):

The intent of each classifier's use is to provide a predicted class label. Thus, the softmax within one neural network is used to generate the vote.  Since it sounds like you have more than one softmax function, you could add together class-specific softmax results and then apply softmax on the sum, but you don't have to.

Enter **ensemble classifier fusion**. Under this approach, classifiers are trained with the same feature sets and training/testing objects, and then classifier votes are combined using the *ensemble majority voting* (EMV) and *ensemble weighted majority voting* (EWMV) ensemble combination techniques [1].  Let $d_{l,\omega}({\bf x}) \in \{0,1\}$ be the decision rule for an object $\mathbf{x}$ by the $l$th classifier $(l=1,2,\ldots,L)$ for class $\omega$ $(\omega=1,2,\ldots,\Omega)$.  The support for EMV and EWMV, respectively, is functionally composed as
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\mu}_\omega({\bf x}) = \sum _{l=1}^L d_{l,\omega}({\bf x}), \quad \quad  d_{l,\omega}({\bf x}) \in \{0,1\},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\mu}_\omega({\bf x}) = \sum _{l=1}^L w_l d_{l,\omega}({\bf x}), \quad \quad  d_{l,\omega}({\bf x}) \in \{0,1\},
\end{equation}
where $w_l$ is the normalized weight reflecting the accuracy of the $l$th classifier.   Here, accuracy is based on the proportion of classified test objects assigned to the diagonal of the confusion matrix divided by the number of test objects.  Let the set of class labels be $\omega=1,2,\ldots,\Omega $ and the ensemble decision for object $\mathbf{x}$ be  $\cal{E}({\bf x}\rightsquigarrow \omega)$.  The decision rule for test object $\mathbf{x}$ is
\begin{equation}
{\cal{E}}({\bf x}\rightsquigarrow \omega) \equiv \arg \underset{c} \max \{ \boldsymbol{\mu}_c({\bf x})\}.
\end{equation}

1. M. van Erp, L. Vuupijl, L. Shomaker. An overview and comparison of voting methods for pattern recognition.  *Proc.  8th Int. Workshop Frontiers in Handwriting Recognition (WFHR02)*.   Hoboken(NJ), IEEE Press, 2002.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't have enough reputation to comment, thus writing this as an answer.*

Do you have an access to the datasets used during training of neural networks? Or at least some labeled dataset?

If so, you can train a separate model that weights the predictions of existing models.
The goal of this new Meta model would be to predict correct class given soft-max values of the existing models as an input.